# How to decrypt an S/MIME encrypted email using openssl smime?

Tags: openssl, decryption, smime

For some reason, I seem unable to find an answer to this basic question. I have received an encrypted S/MIME email, and I want to decrypt it using `openssl smime`. However, I assume I am unable to provide the key in the correct format. This is what I did:

- Saved the the email message (raw text format) as `smime-ok.txt`
- Exported my key from the OS X keychain as `myself.p12`
- Exported my public certificate from the OS X keychain as `myself.cer`

Then I tried

```
openssl smime -decrypt -in smime-ok.txt -recip myself.p12
```

But I get

```
unable to load certificate
37740:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-64.50.7/src/crypto/pem/pem_lib.c:648:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE
```

I also tried `-inkey myself.p12 -recip myself.cer` and some more variants, but that did not make a difference. I guess that my keyfile is not read, or not read properly, because I am not prompted for a password either.

I suspect I may basically misunderstand how to use `openssl smime`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is in fact the case that `openssl smime` expects PEM format in the `-recip` input, but the p12 file is in PKCS12 format. This is how to convert the `p12` file into a `pem` file:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in myself.p12 -out myself.pem
```

After that, the following decrypts the email as expected:

```
openssl smime -decrypt -in smime-ok.txt -recip myself.pem
```